# Covert c# datetime format to java datetime format

Tags: c#, java, android

I'm working in android application, and I'm using c# as a server and RavenDB as database. I'm retrieving the following json array as a response from server

```
"GridRecords":[{ 
"AddedTime":"2013-07-03T19:16:02.3694","TransactId":"CTRF315687490298",
"Status":2,"OtherPartyAccountNo":"364210000001","AmountPaid":100.0,
"AmountRecieved":0.0,"ClosingBalance":674.54,"TransType":8,
"Narration":null,"AddedBy":"Trader-9787457361-Vinoth"}]
```

I need `dd-mm-YYYY` format in java, but when I parse the string(2013-07-03T19:16:02.3694) to java datetime, I get an exception message like unable to parse.

Actually my code look like,

```
        static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            static SimpleDateFormat currentformatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd-MM-yyyy");
    JSONArray ArrayData = data.getJSONArray("GridRecords");
    for (int i = 0; i < ArrayData.length(); i++) {

        JSONObject reportItem = ArrayData.getJSONObject(i);
       Date receiptdate = Date.valueOf(currentformatter.format(formatter.parse(reportItem.getString("AddedTime").toString())));
}
```

Comment: What about [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) do you need help with?

Comment: Give us the actual exception...

Comment: ... and the code which you tried...

Comment: sorry now i have edited with my using code and updated my post

Answer (score 2):

Your format string doesn't match the input date string :

```
// 2013-07-03T19:16:02.3694 <-- date string
static SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

You need to first parse the date string using the `SimpleDateFormat` with pattern `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS` and then you can format the `Date` object with `dd-MM-YYYY` pattern.Remember `MM` is for months , `mm` stands for minutes.

```
String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY").format(
                      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS")
                      .parse(reportItem.getString("AddedTime")));
```

Answer (score 0):

On the C# side use Json.NET and on the Java side use Gson.

I had the same issues as you and both of them work really well together.